# Disable a button (in a data list) after a single click by user

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to disable the button that is contained in a data list row. Is it possible to disable the button after it has been clicked once by the user? If so, can someone please suggest how I can achieve that.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="Qno" OnItemCommand="DataList1_OnItemCommand"
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate> <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ans1") %>' GroupName="qu" />
            <br />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ans2") %>' GroupName="qu" /> <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Submit" CommandName="Validate" />
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have nothing to do with ASP, but if you want javascript (jQuery) solution then you can just do something like

```
$(.once-clickable-button).click(function(){ 
  $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
  // if needed - do what it is supposed to do
});
```

(of course add class "once-clickable-button" to the button or chose the name that suits you)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function checkEnableSubmit() {
     document.getElementById("Button2").disabled = true;
   }
</script>
```

call this method on the onclick event when u want to disable the button

Answer (score 0):

With javascript you could do something like the following:

```
document.getElementById("buttonID").disabled = true
```

Comment: of course if you're jquery mkk's solution works just as well. I just wasn't sure if you were using any outside sources.